# Add HTML on product screen admin side

Tags: html, wordpress, hook

I am looking for a solution to add extra HTML on the screen from the post_type 'product' on the admin site.

I know you can add metaboxes but this is not what I want.
If I look in the inspector from my browser I see all the content is settled in the div below

```
<div id="wpcontent">
```

Is there somebody who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action( 'edit_form_advanced', 'add_extra_html' );

function top_form_edit( $post ) {
    if( 'product' == $post->post_type ) {
        //do some cool stuff
    }
}
```

The code above add the HTML after the editor and metaboxes. There are different hooks to do this. Take a look at [Wordpress Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php/)